# ABNewPersonViewController internationalization

Tags: ios4, addressbook, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I am using ABNewPersonViewController to add new contact in my app, but the it's always in English. How can I change the locale settings so it's possible to display in the language set by the user in the iPhone settings.app? Thanks.